# is Oracle ADF Mobile free? and what is it's usage scope?

Tags: java, mobile, oracle

I would like to know whether Oracle ADF Mobile is free to use for someone who doesn't  have the (expensive) ADF license, and what if I want to talk to a backend (web service), do I need Weblogic?

What about usage scope? Is ADF Mobile suitable for games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turned out to be not free, 
cost :
USD$ 120.00 per named user, or
USD$ 5800.00 per processor
and if you want to deploy your app say to app store you need processor license.

> Oracle FAQ :
>   A named user plus license of ADF will entitle customer a single
>   named user license of the ADF Mobile. 
>   A processor license of ADF will allow customer to deploy ADF Mobile-based application to
>   unlimited number of devices.

I'm still though unclear about whether it's suited for games but there is a hint :

> Oracle FAQ: You may even add a feature based on
>   device-native code. All of these can run within the same application,
>   and all of these features can communicate with each other.

hope someone else shed more light more about making games with ADF mobile.

Comment: Any update for this answer?? because still they are charging for the Oracle ADF Mobile service?? if so what is the cost?? can you please share the link.

Comment: @WannaCoffee sorry I was AFK for quite a while but if you need the link to license here it is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfmobilefaq-1866697.pdf

Comment: @WannaCoffee it says "ADF Mobile is licensed as part of the Oracle Application
Development Framework (ADF). Oracle ADF can be licensed either
as “Oracle Application Development Framework and TopLink” item
on the technology price list, or as part of the Oracle WebLogic
licenses." 
you can go then check the current price it on their separate pricing page here http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf